# how transform center map in address flutter

Tags: flutter, geolocation, maps

I use this code to generate the map. I would need, however, that when the user moves the map he gives me the coordinates of the center.
I would then have to transform the coordinates into the street. can anyone help me?

```
                                      FlutterMap(
                                        mapController: _mapController,
                                        options: MapOptions(
                                          center: coordinates,
                                          minZoom: 6.132941532936457,
                                          maxZoom: 18.499999,
                                        ),
                                        layers: [
                                          TileLayerOptions(
                                            urlTemplate:'',
                                            additionalOptions: {
                                              'accessToken':
                                                  _mapboxKey.value!,
                                              'id':
                                                  'mapbox.mapbox-streets-v7',
                                            },
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can use **geolocator**

This is the link for this package
https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator

It will give

1 Get the last known location
2 Get the current location of the device
3 Get continuous location updates
4 Check if location services are enabled on the device
5 Calculate the distance (in meters) between two geocoordinates
6 Calculate the bearing between two geocoordinates

and using **geocode package**

this is the link
https://pub.dev/packages/geocode

Package to make Geocode requests. It exposes two methods to translate coordinates into locations and addresses into coordinates.

using coordinates you can use maps